# ks test in Python returns the exact same p-values for 2 different sets of data

Tags: python

Good morning, I have 3 sets of data that represent the average distance run by mice from 3 different groups characterized by different genotypes (WT, Hz, KO) each minutes during an experiment that lasted 90.

The 3 sets are different, and I want to get the significance of their difference using ks-test (I think it's the right test, as each set represents the distribution of the distances run by the mice of the different genotypes across the experiment).

Yet, for some reason, when I run the ks-tests (scipy.stats.kstest and scipy.stats.ks_2samp), the comparison KO/Hz and KO/WT return the exact same statistics and p-values, even if the sets of data for WT and Hz are different.

Here are the sets of data:

```
np.array(WT_increments)
```

Out[73]:
array([ 9.88, 11.48,  9.36,  7.02,  8.64, 13.96,  9.94,  8.22,  5.98,
6.3 ,  7.9 , 11.06, 10.52,  8.72,  7.86,  4.64,  9.46,  9.9 ,
5.1 ,  4.72,  5.32,  7.2 ,  6.82,  7.08,  8.  ,  7.02,  8.06,
8.82,  6.24,  6.64,  6.84,  7.06,  6.44,  5.26,  6.  ,  7.72,
6.54,  6.24,  5.8 ,  5.3 ,  3.56,  2.78,  4.26,  4.88,  2.72,
3.62,  4.38,  3.86,  5.3 ,  3.4 ,  2.32,  3.78,  3.08,  3.32,
2.58,  0.8 ,  1.16,  1.64,  2.16,  4.04,  1.3 ,  1.14,  1.12,
0.9 ,  2.04,  2.2 ,  3.08,  3.02,  1.52,  1.86,  3.06,  3.4 ,
3.04,  3.22,  2.96,  2.98,  1.26,  2.04,  1.14,  1.  ,  0.8 ,
0.64,  0.84,  1.04,  0.78,  0.56,  1.88,  1.84,  1.74,  2.08])

```
np.array(Hz_increments)
```

Out[74]:
array([10.65,  6.75,  8.95, 14.75, 12.75, 10.35,  7.4 , 10.25, 10.85,
10.25,  7.35, 13.2 , 13.05, 10.85,  5.35,  2.75, 10.15, 12.7 ,
11.85, 11.7 , 10.25,  6.95,  8.15, 10.45,  8.05, 10.4 ,  8.1 ,
8.5 , 10.95,  7.35,  9.45,  8.  ,  7.15,  4.55, 10.45,  9.7 ,
7.35,  7.4 ,  6.95,  6.6 ,  4.65,  6.4 ,  3.85,  7.25,  7.1 ,
9.4 ,  5.75,  6.  ,  3.65,  1.6 ,  2.25,  4.9 ,  5.75,  5.3 ,
6.6 ,  5.7 ,  6.7 ,  3.45,  1.25,  1.55,  1.1 ,  1.8 ,  3.15,
1.65,  0.95,  0.9 ,  1.25,  1.9 ,  3.25,  7.2 ,  7.3 ,  2.6 ,
1.15,  0.95,  0.75,  0.9 ,  1.05,  0.7 ,  0.65,  1.  ,  0.15,
0.5 ,  1.7 ,  2.  ,  4.1 ,  6.35,  1.8 ,  0.75,  4.05,  4.25])

`np.array(KO_increments)`

Out[75]:
array([ 9.88,  8.04,  6.62, 12.28, 11.04,  9.46, 10.5 ,  9.82,  9.14,
9.6 ,  8.72,  7.76,  8.6 ,  8.64,  8.8 ,  9.68,  9.54,  8.  ,
9.7 ,  6.7 ,  6.14,  5.18,  5.48,  6.34,  8.22,  8.06,  8.56,
7.6 ,  7.14,  6.94,  5.22,  5.54,  5.82,  5.78,  6.3 ,  5.8 ,
7.36,  7.7 ,  6.36,  4.6 ,  2.78,  4.14,  4.7 ,  4.58,  5.76,
6.78,  5.54,  4.68,  4.9 ,  5.54,  5.9 ,  4.4 ,  3.42,  4.04,
3.46,  3.06,  1.28,  2.62,  2.9 ,  5.66,  4.96,  5.64,  3.28,
3.54,  3.5 ,  2.94,  2.9 ,  2.92,  2.12,  0.88,  1.3 ,  1.22,
1.96,  2.1 ,  3.1 ,  3.06,  3.38,  3.1 ,  2.8 ,  4.24,  5.8 ,
4.68,  3.78,  1.92,  1.92,  1.32,  0.5 ,  1.4 ,  1.8 ,  3.04])

To help you better visualize the differences, I join here the average distances walked by the 3 groups of mice across the experiment (just the plot of the cumulated values of the 3 arrays).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19EFM.png)

And here are the results of the ks tests run on the sets of data:

```
scipy.stats.ks_2samp(np.array(WT_increments), np.array(KO_increments), alternative='two-sided')
`Out[76]: KstestResult(statistic=0.17777777777777778, pvalue=0.11640971788193923)`

`scipy.stats.ks_2samp(np.array(Hz_increments), np.array(KO_increments), alternative='two-sided')`
`Out[77]: KstestResult(statistic=0.17777777777777778, pvalue=0.11640971788193923)`

`scipy.stats.ks_2samp(np.array(Hz_increments), np.array(WT_increments), alternative='two-sided')`
`Out[78]: KstestResult(statistic=0.2111111111111111, pvalue=0.035951044858723816)`
```

As you can see, the result for the ks-test is exactly the same in the comparison Hz/KO and in the comparison WT/KO, which feels really odd.

I didn't find the exact code Python is using to make its calculation of the statistic here, it would be useful to understand what's going on.

Does anybody have an idea of the reasons why this is happening?  If the result of the test doesn't account for the differences in the sets of data that are given to it, it makes me feel really suspicious of its reliability.

Another quick question, I had at first started to run the ks-test on the cumulated distance run by the mice over the experiment (i.e the values showed on the picture) and not on the lists of distances run at each minute. The result of the Hz/KO and WT/KO comparisons remained identical in both cases, but the statistics and p-values returned in the two cases were different. I think the correct way of doing a ks-test is to do it on the increments and not on the cumulated values, anybody agrees ?